# Display an image linked to an object instance in wxPython

Tags: python, image, wxpython, python-imaging-library

My end goal is, to be able to display multiple Images belonging to instances of python objects in a wx.Panel/Window/ whatever would do that best. I am very new to GUI programming and so I 'd be grateful for any advice.

My thought process so far was as follows:
I create an object instance (let us just say I want to display a card game ) that has an attribute image. This image is loaded into the object via PIL.Image, as by doing so I can further work on the image. 
I now want to display this image in a wxPanel, but I want to make sure that the image is still linked to the object instance.

How do I do this? Is the Pillow framework and its Image object suitable for what I am trying to do?

```
import os
from PIL import Image
images = [Image.open((r"path")) for d in os.listdir(r"path")]
cards = [Card(color, value) for color in self.COLORS for value in self.VALUES]
for i,card in enumerate(cards):
      card.image = self.images[i]
```

As you can see, I saved all objects to a list, I would now try to show this list on a panel by showing the card.image attribute on screen. Going from there would be to implement drag&drop for said objects.

Comment: you need to use `wx.Image`, and load it into a `wx.StaticBitmap` (which is a gui element you can use just like a button or a frame or any other wx Element)

Comment: thanks a lot... I seem to have overcomplicated the whole thing.

Comment: note that pygame *may* make more sense for this than wxPython (I love wxPython ... but its a questionable choice for a game...(not that you cant make a card game with it...))